# iOS strange text displaying in UILabels

Tags: ios, swift, label, uilabel

I have very strange problem with displaying text in UILabels. On one of them text is shown correctly - it's "„" sign - lower quotation mark. What I get on others is "w" with the apostrophe "'" above it. Those labels are bonded to the same property and displays the same text. There are no runtime attributes assigned to any of them, no changes in their properties in code behind.
I even tried to copy the correct label - it did't help

Outlets : 
`@IBOutlet weak var companyNameLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!`

Assignement:

```
titleLabel.text = ad?.title
companyNameLabel.text = ad?.title
```

Both are plain text, font - ubuntu 16 px, same color, alignment - center, lines - 2, and as I wrote above every other settings are the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, it looks like an iOS or interface builder internal bug. The text printed by ubuntu font is displaying properly only if the entire string occupies only one line in UILabel

Answer (score 0):

That lower quote mark character may not be defined in the font you're using. Check the font you've selected for each label. Then try to enter the "„" character in that font and see what you get.

Comment: The fonts and sizes are the same in all of the labels

Comment: Are you positive? Have you double, even triple-checked? Something's not right. And what do you mean "bonded to the same property?" iOS doesn't support key-value binding like Mac OS does, so you have to write explicit code to set the labels. Edit your answer to show the outlets, label settings, and the code that sets your labels.